# What can cause location.href to be undefined?

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-domain

I have a javascript SDK that sends cross domain requests to my server with the current url in the query data. I log this data on my server.

Occasionally my logs show that the location is `undefined`.

Here is my code:

```
send(location.href);
```

What can cause `location.href` to be undefined?

Answer (score 3):

Internet Explorer 11 sets `location.href` to `undefined` when the URL is a local `file://` url.

---

It's likely that developers using your SDK are testing their sites locally by opening the files in Internet Explorer 11. So instead of receiving a `file://` url, you receive `undefined`